# Unable to get the document to load on my website made using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

So I am creating an employee registration form and I am trying to attach documents on the webpage, which need to be acknowledged before going to the next step. The problem I am facing is the document is failing to load on the webpage, and also that my webpage throws me this error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGgOC.png)

Here is the code for my webpage, FYI I am just calling this page in App.js

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

function EmployeeRegistration() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    fullName: '',
    gender: '',
    aadhaarNumber: '',
    dateofBirth: null,
    maritalStatus: '',
    emergencyContactName: '',
    address: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    emailID: '',
    emergencyContactNumber: '',
    jobTitle: '',
    departmentName: '',
    joiningDate: '',
    employmentType: '',
    education: [],
    workExperience: [],
    relevantSkills: '',
    pfUAN:'',
    esiNO:'',
    documentAcknowledged: false,
  });

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setUserData({ ...userData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleAddEducation = () => {
    setUserData({
      ...userData,
      education: [...userData.education, { degree: '', graduationYear: '', grade: '' }],
    });
  };

  const handleRemoveEducation = (index) => {
    const updatedEducation = [...userData.education];
    updatedEducation.splice(index, 1);
    setUserData({ ...userData, education: updatedEducation });
  };

  const handleEducationChange = (index, event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const updatedEducation = [...userData.education];
    updatedEducation[index][name] = value;
    setUserData({ ...userData, education: updatedEducation });
  };
  
  const handleAddWorkExperience = () => {
    setUserData({
      ...userData,
      workExperience: [...userData.workExperience, { companyName: '', designation: '', duration: '' }],
    });
  };

  const handleRemoveWorkExperience = (index) => {
    const updatedWorkExperience = [...userData.workExperience];
    updatedWorkExperience.splice(index, 1);
    setUserData({ ...userData, workExperience: updatedWorkExperience });
  };

  //omitted parts which weren't necessary on here
        <h2>Social Security Numbers</h2>
        <label>
          PF UAN number:
          <input
            type="number"
            name="pfUAN"
            value={userData.bdpmName}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          ESI Number:
          <input
            type="number"
            name="esiNO"
            value={userData.esiNO}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <div>
          {/* Document display and acknowledgement */}
          <h3>Document</h3>
          <Document
            file="../Docs/test.pdf" // Specify the path to your PDF document
            onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
          >
            <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
          </Document>
          {!userData.documentAcknowledged && (
            <button type="button" onClick={handleDocumentAcknowledgement}>
              Acknowledge Document
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default EmployeeRegistration;
```

Comment: The path is wrong. Do you serve the pdf correctly?

Comment: I don't think so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You ara making things too complex,its hard to find the typo error.
You didn't need `useState` to *get data from forms*.

Instead, You can use native browse support `new FormData` API, This makes your code more readable and maintaninable.

For example, simple form element

```
function MyForm(){

    function submit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = new FormData(e.target); // Magic is here
        console.log(form.get('username'));
        /** Rest of API calls */
    }
    
    return(
        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            <label for='username'>
                Username:
            </label>
            <input id='username' name='username'></input>
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

No more `useState` , `onChage` event